# Rails 5 - belongs_to throws validation errors when data is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5.1.3 with Mongoid 6.2.1, I am getting a validation error when data is valid. Here are the 2 classes I have noticed an issue with so far:

character.rb

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :characters
belongs_to :bdo_class, class_name: 'BDOClass'
```

user.rb

```
has_many :characters, inverse_of: :user
```

I do `user.characters.new(...)` with BDO class specified, I save it and it saves.

If I then do a character search and save, eg;

```
ch = Character.where(:name => 'MyCharacter').first
ch.save!
```

I get a validation error: `User can't be blank, Bdo class can't be blank`

If I check `ch.user_id` myself I can see that the field is correct and valid, it references the ObjectId that it should.

I looked up possible fixes for this issue in Rails 5, all recommended I set `optional: true` on the classes. However I would like this field to be required. It also doesn't fix the issue because `ch.user` still returns nil.

Result of `Character.where(:name => 'Drahcir').first`

```
#<Character _id: 5a099cbabc80b75e845a997a, name: "Drahcir", name_case: "drahcir", level: "58", ap: 0, aap: 0, dp: 0, is_primary: true, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('5a099b48bc80b75e03a4ac3e'), bdo_class_id: BSON::ObjectId('5a098e86bc80b75998d141c9')>
```

Result of `User.where(:username => 'Nishikin').first`

```
#<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('5a099d6dbc80b75ee6e6d2d7'), guild_master: nil, member: nil, officer: nil, user_case: "nishikin", username: "Nishikin">
```

Sergio pointed out in the comments that user_id does not match the _id of the parent user. Which leads me to the question of why `user.characters.new(...)` linked the wrong ObjectId, same goes for the reference to BDOClass.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Remove `inverse_of` option. You don't need it in your default case. Please open console `rails c` and paste output from `Character.where(:name => 'Drahcir').first`

Comment: `ch.user_id` might hold an object id value, but, apparently, there's no user with this id.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, can't believe I missed that. Strange though since the Character was made using `user.characters.new(...)`.